# Numpy mask : dimension loss

Tags: numpy, matrix, indexing, mask, tensor

I struggle with mask and numpy. I have a 3D-tensor and I try to select only some specific cells.

More preciseley I create a 3D tensor :

```
array = np.repeat(np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)[None,:],3, axis = 0)
# array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]])
```

and I want to have remove the first row of the first matrix, the second row of the second matrix etc... So in order to have :

```
# array([[[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]]])
```

I precise that I want to do it with a code of this form :
`array[mask]`

(I don't want to reshape or select indexes and mask.array for its performance).

I created a mask :

```
mask = [[False ,True ,True],
       [True ,False ,True],
       [False, True, True]]
```

But it lost a dimension :

```
array[mask]
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Thank you very much for the help !

Comment: What's wrong with `reshape` on the result? It doesn't cause any significant performance loss

Comment: Because a `mask` like this can select different numbers of "rows", `arr[mask]` can only return a flattened result.  The knowledge that each row of `mask` has 2 True, is yours, and not something that `numpy` checks for.  You have to reshape, or construct the equivalent indexing arrays (`using `np.where` and `reshape`).

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! I didn't want to reshape to make the code shorter but I will have to.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to achieve what you want using boolean masks. The behavior you're seeing is described in [numpy's indexing guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). In particular:

> In general if an index includes a Boolean array, the result will be identical to inserting `obj.nonzero()` into the same position and using the integer array indexing mechanism described above. `x[ind_1, boolean_array, ind_2]` is equivalent to `x[(ind_1,) + boolean_array.nonzero() + (ind_2,)]`.

In your case, `np.nonzero(mask)` would produce two 1 dimensional arrays, which means your mask indexes the first two dimensions of `array` which is replaced by a single dimension (since the `np.nonzero(mask)` results broadcast to a 1-D array).

You could achieve what you want by indexing the first two dimensions of the data `array` with two 2-d arrays, but I'm not sure whether that falls under your definition of not wanting to "select indexes". Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.repeat(np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)[None,:],3, axis = 0)

# Tuple of (3, 1) and (3, 2) shaped array which broadcasts to (3, 2) subspace
idx = [[0], [1], [2]], [[1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 1]]

out = array[idx]
```

out:

```
array([[[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer ! With your explanation, I have no choice but use indexing or reshape. Very great answer, thanks !